C2039: 'member' is not a member of "namespace"::"class"
Inside of this header file here
namespace seneca {
    class TimeMonitor {
        std::string m_EventName;
        std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point m_EventTime;
    public:
        void startEvent(const char*);
        Event stopEvent(); //no errors come up here but I suspect this is where everything is going wrong
    };
}

The member function Event stopEvent() is meant to create a class object of Event type and return that object. I don't think that the implementation of the function is where my code breaks but I'll post it here:
namespace seneca {
    seneca::Event TimeMonitor::stopEvent() {
            return Event(m_EventName.c_str(), m_EventTime - std::chrono::steady_clock::now()); //This line gives me build errors for m_EventName and m_EventTime, calling them undeclared identifiers, even though visual studio recognises and autofills them when I start typing their names here
    }
}

Then in main(), where I actually call the function, it gives "stopEvent() is not a member of seneca::TimeMonitor" at each point where I call it.
Notably this behaviour does not occur for any of my other methods or members in this class, void startEvent(const char*) works completely fine.
I've tried typing and retyping the declaration in the header file in case of those notorious invisible characters, but aside from that I genuinely have no idea what could be wrong with this.

Welcome to Stackoverflow. Edit your question to provide a minimal reproducible example.
Without one diagnosis is speculation.
